# Common center of mass

Tags: physics

Suppose I have $n$ areas of masses $m_1, m_2, ... ,m_n$, each with a center of mass $[x_i, y_i]$. They have no intersections between them - the areas are exclusive.

If I consider them all as one body (one area), what is their center of mass? Is it this:

$$x = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n m_ix_i}{\sum_{i=0}^n m_i}$$ ?

Comment: Why would you think not?  Or: what is your working definition of center of mass?  Finally, where did the $y_i$ go in your displayed formula: do you mean $[x,y]=\sum m_i[x_i,y_i]/\sum m_i$ ?  Or has $x$ become a vector between your first formula and the last one?

Comment: The common center of mass would be $[x, y]$, but I chose not to include the calculation of $y$ as it is exactly the same one. I just need to know it is correct, because I can't find a mistake in my calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may consider such model. Your formula is true.